# Getting a list of enums broken on ruby 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just updated my rails app from ruby 2.7.0 to 3.2.2 and a following code:

```
class TemplateField < ApplicationRecord
  enum group: {
    'primary':    'primary',
    'secondary':  'secondary',
    'auxiliary':  'auxiliary',
    'header':     'header',
    'back':       'back',
    'unassigned': 'unassigned'
  }
end

class Template < ApplicationRecord
  TemplateField.groups.each do |_key, val|
    has_many "fields_#{val.pluralize}".to_sym #...
  end
end
```

Broke with a following message:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `groups' for TemplateField:Class
```

Basically, also calling `TemplateField.groups` directly in console produces the same error. Does anything changed between ruby 2.7 and 3.2 that I should be aware of?

Comment: Are you also updating Rails? This seems more like a Rails change rather than a Ruby change. If so, from which version to which?

Comment: I would be very wary of using `group` as the name of an enum or attribute as it clashes with a very important class method in ActiveRecord.

Comment: @max in such situation using `:_suffix` or `:_prefix` option is safe

Comment: @mechnicov except for the potential developer confusion that occurs when one of your columns has the same name as a SQL keyword...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you're showing us, that will work. Any chance you have another `TemplateField` class defined somewhere?

Comment: Nope, it's happening for every single call to get any enum keys for any model. It's like this entire feature of rails is broken after upgrading to 3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, that was caused by outdated `sorbet-rails` dependency. Running `bundle update sorbet sorbet-rails` fixed the issue for me.